# A Complicated MySQL Query

Tags: mysql

I want to perform a very complicated Query on a MySQL Table. Currently this MySQL Table stores user info like **IP, Country, *event_id* and many other statistics like date_start date_end for specific events**.

**A specific event_id starts with date_start** and when the user ends it **a time() value is being written to the date_end column.**

I want a query to find somehow all the `suspicous` users (`ids return`). Below are the rules that defines a suspicous user.

- There are rows in the database for the `user_id` that has been connected from multiple countries. ***In this case where the `country column` has different values***
- There are many rows in the database ***for a specific event_id*** that the **`SUM` OF (date_end-date_start)** has a value for example `+50%`  than all the other **SUM of (date-end-date_start) of others events.** With a simple words, the query should report the user_ids that have spent too much time on some events whereas they didn't spend too much time on all the others. The % percent value should be configurable.

I know it sounds crazy, however i tried to do it and i failed so much. I did that using PHP but it's slow and i'm sure that it can be done with queries.

Hope you understand me

Thank you

Comment: Initial problem: post the result of `describe table;` for each of the tables involved. Then post a sample export of `select * from table;` for each of the tables. Finally, post an example of a sample output you would like to achieve. Especially for sql problems, proper formatting and expression of the problematic is key to getting answers. Good luck. ps: your problem seems much easier than you make it think.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is too big.  Figure out how to find the users who have come from multiple countries.  Then figure out how to get statistics on event durations.  Then figure out how to identify outliers.  Then, finally, try to merge all three solutions.

In general, use SQL to filter the data down to a manageable size, then PHP to do any further processing.